# Woocommerce products page image sizing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How I can change the way woocommerce show my products image in products catalog page? Woocommerce doesn't show the uploaded images in correct cropping format and the pictures don't look ok. Here's an example: [image]I have tried customized>WooCommers>Product Images>Thumbnail cropping but it doesn't solve the problem for me. The pictures get cropped while I want to show the whole image on the square frame. This is not good if I want to show a pictures with different dimensions! What should I do? I use Flatsome theme.

Comment: You should post the URL :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images > select "Uncropped". This should make it so that the original aspect ratio doesn't change, so if all the images are for example a 5:4 aspect ratio, your category/catalog page thumbnails should all be 5:4 images instead of square. If you truly want all the images to look the same (or all be squares), you'll need to re-upload them as the same aspect ratio.